# Как сделать так что б из json файла выпадали children?

Tags: ajax, json

Как сделать так что б из `json` файла выпадали `children`?

```
[
    {
        "name": "child11",
        "y": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "child12",
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "name": "child13",
        "y": 8
    },
     {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "child14",
        "y": -12,
        "children": [
                    {"name": "child11", "y": 1},
                    {"name": "child12", "y": 2},
                    {"name": "child13", "y": -3},
                    {"name": "child14", "y": 4}
                ]
            }
]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kSEkC7VCZTkmp303ieGl?p=preview

Comment: что значит _из json файла выпадали children_?